# Proving a set of complex numbers is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm reading Lang's Complex Analysis (GTM 103) as an introduction to complex analysis. I came across the theorem which states that a set of complex numbers is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded.

The definitions used in the book is presented below:

**Accumulation points**
Let $S$ be a set of complex numbers. Let $\{z_n\}$ be a sequence in $s$. By a point of accumulation of $\{z_n\}$ we mean a complex number $v$ such that given $\epsilon$ (always assumed > 0) there exist infinitely many integers $n$ such that
$$|z_n-v|<\epsilon$$

**Compact sets**  We define a set of complex numbers $S$ to be compact if every sequence of elements of $S$ has a point of accumulation in $S$.

**Compact sets (alternative def'n)** Every sequence of elements of $S$ has a convergent subsequence whose limit is in $S$.

While trying to prove the forward direction ($S$ is compact $\implies S$ is closed), the book says:

> To show $S$ is closed, let $v$ be in its closure. Given $n$, there exists $z\in S$ such that$$|z_n-v|<1/n$$The sequence ${z_n}$ converges to $v$, and has a subsequence converging to a limit in $S$ because $S$ is assumed compact. This limit must be $v$, whence
> $v\in S$ and $S$ is closed.

I'm having trouble understanding this part, could someone please explain why given $n$, there exists $z\in S$ such that$$|z_n-v|<1/n$$ is true? Thank you!

Comment: This isn't specific to complex numbers. It's a fact about $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. This is the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: @ZoeAllen It’s even a fact about all complete metric spaces wherein every bounded set is totally bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Lang's book:

> Let $S$ be a subset of the plane. A **boundary point** of $S$ is a point $\alpha$ such that **every** disc $D(\alpha, r)$ centered at $\alpha$ and of radius $r > 0$ contains both points of $S$ and points not in $S$.
> ...
> The **closure** of a set $S$ is defined to be the union of $S$ and all its
> boundary points.

We consider $v$ be in the closure of the compact $S$ and want to show that $v \in S$. We know that $v \in S$ or $v$ is a boundary point of $S$ (of course both may be true). The case $v \in S$ is trivial, we can take $z_n = v$ for all $n$. If $v$ is a boundary point of $S$, each $D(v, r)$ with $r > 0$ contains a point of $S$. Thus for each $n$ there exists $z_n \in D(v, 1/n) \cap S$. This means $\lvert z_n - v \rvert < 1/n$.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant and detailed answer! I finally understood it now. Also just a follow-up question, if a complex sequence converges to $v$, do all of its convergent subsequences converge to $v$?

Comment: @HetianFu Yes, that is true!

Answer (score 0):

If $S$ *isn't* closed, intuitively it means there is some gap in it, $v$, such that $S$ gets arbitrarily close to $v$ but doesn't contain it. That means for any distance $\frac{1}{n}$ there is some point in $S$ within $\frac{1}{n}$ of $v$.

That means the set of $z$ in $S$ such that $|z−v|>\frac{1}{n}$ never contains all of $S$, even though the union of those sets for all $n$ does contain the whole of $S$. As such, this is an open cover of $S$ with no finite subcover.

So if $S$ isn't closed, it can't be compact. And conversely, if it is compact, it must be closed.

Comment: I didn't know the definition of compact sets in terms of open covers, but thanks for the alternative proof!